# batch monitor a folder and unzip each file

Tags: batch-file, logging, compare, unzip

our ERP program generates .zip files containing .xml documents.
i need to make sure each .zip file is extracted to destination folder.
i found a batch script that compares two log files  but i cant figure out how to process the new (yet not unzipped) files

```
   @echo off
   if not exist c:\OldDir.txt echo. > c:\OldDir.txt
   dir /b "C:\Spektra\Gelen" > c:\NewDir.txt
   set equal=no
   fc c:\OldDir.txt c:\NewDir.txt | find /i "no differences" > nul && set   equal=yes
  copy /y c:\Newdir.txt c:\OldDir.txt > nul
  if %equal%==yes goto :eof
  rem Your batch file lines go here
  **********
  c:\unzip.exe (the_new_files) -d (destination)
  *******************
```

here is the script

i need to process new files that don't exist on the old log file

thanks

Comment: I would go a different route. The archive attribute is most likely set on all new files.  So I would just list the files that have the archive attribute set and unzip those files.  When you are done unzipping the file use the `attrib` command to turn the archive attribute off.  This will take some setup to begin with.  Any files that have already been unzipped you would need to turn off the archive attribute on them.

Comment: great idea. i tried to use the current date and time of operation in the log file for the reference and unzip later files, however i could not find out how to list files newer than a certain datetime.

Answer (score 1):

To find out which lines have been added to the new log file `C:\NewDir.txt` with respect to the old one `OldDir.txt` you could use the [`findstr` command](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html), which features the option `/G` to specify a file containing the search strings. Together with `/X` (exact match) and `/V` (return non-matching lines), only those lines of `NewDir.txt` are returned which have been added, supposing every line is unique:

```cmd
findstr /V /X /I /G:"C:\OldDir.txt" "C:\NewDir.txt"
```

To process the returned items, use a [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) to capture them:

```cmd
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%F in ('
    findstr /V /X /I /G:"C:\OldDir.txt" "C:\NewDir.txt"
') do (
    rem // Do whatever you want with each file in `%%F`...
)
```

So your script might look like this:

```cmd
@echo off
rem // Change to the working directory `C:\` once:
pushd "C:\" || exit /B 1 & rem/ ("C:\" is the root directory of drive "C:")
rem // Ensure `OldDir.txt` exists by appending nothing:
>> "OldDir.txt" rem/
rem // Create new log file `NewDir.txt`:
> "NewDir.txt" dir /B "C:\Spektra\Gelen"
rem // Process all newly added items in `NewDir`:
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%F in ('
    findstr /V /X /I /G:"OldDir.txt" "NewDir.txt"
') do (
    rem // Do whatever you want with each file in `%%F`:
    unzip "%%F" -d "C:\some\destination\folder"
)
rem // Move new log file onto old one, suppress report message:
> nul move /Y "NewDir.txt" "OldDir.txt"
rem // Restore previous working directory:
popd
```